# Attach string for matching substring

Tags: python, regex, regexp-replace

I have the following string

```
test = "if row['adm.w'] is 'Bad' and row['rem'] not empty"
```

I want to add `str(...)` for those tokens which are `row[...]`, how can I do this in regex? I came up with this and it's not working as intended:

```
re.sub(r"'([^row[']*)'", r"str(['\1'])", test)
```

I want the end result to be

```
test = "if str(row['adm.w']) is 'Bad' and str(row['rem']) not empty"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
>>> re.sub(r"(row\[.*?\])", r"str(\1)", test)
"if str(row['adm.w']) is 'Bad' and str(row['rem']) not empty"
```